Why is FlatList asking me to render string in a text while it is already done?
I am trying to display a FlatList. I took the example from the docs but it is not working.
I have the error:
Render Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

I have tried all things, removing quotes from strings, creating arrays and so on.
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 22,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
});

const ListeEcoles = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={[
          {key: 'Devin'},
          {key: 'Dan'},
          {key: 'Dominic'},
          {key: 'Jackson'},
          {key: 'James'},
          {key: 'Joel'},
          {key: 'John'},
          {key: 'Jillian'},
          {key: 'Jimmy'},
          {key: 'Julie'},
        ]}
        renderItem={ ({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text> }
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default ListeEcoles;


How are you sure this is coming from this component?

The error message

Render Error: Text strings must be rendered within a Text component.

occurs in React Native when you attempt to render text directly inside a component that does not support text rendering, such as View.
In React Native, text content must always be wrapped inside a Text component to be properly displayed.
Incorrect Usage:
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      Hello, world! {/* This will cause the error */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

Corrected Code:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hello, world!</Text> {/* Correct usage */}
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;

